# How to check ECDSA key fingerprint that I am USING to a server instead of the one proposed?

Tags: ssh, fingerprint

Keep in mind I don't want the fingerprint I obtain when doing `ssh localhost`. I want the key I might have accepted and am currently using in the server...

Comment: can you edit your post with copy/pastes from the command line?  You can change the fingerprints you paste into your post, for security.  It'll be clearer what you want to do if you make your post a lot longer with what is going on on the command line and why it's not what you want and why you want what you want

Comment: If a known key fingerprint changes, SSH will refuse to connect. I don’t see how the scenario in your question could ever occur.